# Transfer files between two Android phones over WiFi

Tags: android, file-synchronization

***Summary:*** Looking for software to transfer files between 2 Android phones over WiFi.

***Required features:***

- **Ease of setup.**

  If I want complicated, I can just run FTP servers on them and use FTP clients.

  Ideally, all the setup I want is to either enter the IP of another phone, or better yet list devices on local WiFi network and let me pick one. Even better if it autofilters for devices with identical software installed.
- Ability to transfer an **entire directory** (not required to sync... just assume fresh directory NOT present on transfer phone)
- VERY **lightweight** when not in use.

  - Either ability to permanently exit with no background service; OR background service that's extremely low memory footprint - under 1 MB - and no resource usage when idle.
- Ability to read/write any files on filesystem, more specifically, on **external SD card**.
- **No reliance on cloud storage** or ANY infrastructure aside from these 2 phones
- Compatible with Android 4.3 and 4.4
- Retry capability if transfer gets interruted

---

***Optional desired features***

- Ability to remember what the last phone you connected to was; or which directories were used last.
- Cost: preferably gratis. But I don't require that.
- **Reasonable speed** (e.g. shouldn't be any more than 2x slower than FTP). But I'm willing to tolerate slower transfer speed for higher quality features

---

***NOT required/needed:***

- ability to operate from a single phone. E.g. I'm fine if I have to pick a source directory on source phone but a target directory on target phone
- Ability to transfer over non-WiFi.

Comment: A little contradiction not solvable by apps without root: "write […] on external SD card" and "Compatible with Android 4.4". Unless solved on system level, arbitrary apps cannot write on arbitrary directories on external SD cards with Kitkat. Some manufacturers have fixed that themselves (e.g. Huawei for the Ascend P6), but most have not.

Comment: Are both the Android phones rooted?

Comment: Not the target one

Answer (score 3):

Try this [Es File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

Select any file by holding it while browsing, you will get option to share go ahead and click it.

Now select option 'Send by LAN'

Now it will give you option to create wifi hotspot as server

Just join that wifi from other phone and voila you can send file directly using your phone's wifi.

Comment: Can it do a whole directory?

Comment: yes there is a 'send' option instead of 'share' i just checked it. It will start scanning network for connected devices. Why don't you give it a shot it's a small app to download.

Answer (score 1):

[Sweech](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sweech&hl=en) solved my problem. Click **directory** icon to select it, and then **download** button at the top. It is **easy to setup** - just a web server that shares Android files, which asks for permissions at run-time. No cloud storage needed. **Good speed**. Option to prevent it from running in background. Ability to write to external SD card.